# MAUI not updating UI on MVVM Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I have a MAUI application that changes the language on the interface according to a language picker menu. The application was in Xamarin and I am porting it to MAUI: in Xamarin all worked perfectly, but not in MAUI. Basically the UI does not update according to MVVM bindings using onpropertychanged. I am not understanding what is wrong.

Here is my XAML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:CustomViews="clr-namespace:HeatLoadApp_MAUI.CustomViews"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             x:Class="HeatLoadApp_MAUI.SettingsPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:HeatLoadApp_MAUI.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="ViewModels:SettingsViewModel">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
                <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
            <CustomViews:CustomNavigationBar Grid.Row="0" TitleText="{Binding Settings}"/>

            <Grid RowSpacing="20" Padding="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--LANGUAGE SELECTION-->
                    <Label
                        x:Name="lblLanguage"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="{Binding Language}"/>

                    <Picker
                        x:Name="pickerLanguage"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Title="Select language"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageList}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>

            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my code behind

```
using HeatLoadApp_MAUI.ViewModels;

namespace HeatLoadApp_MAUI;

public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{
    //this is the viewmodel for this page
    SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();

    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = settingsViewModel;
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using HeatLoadApp_MAUI.Utilities;

namespace HeatLoadApp_MAUI.ViewModels
{
    public class SettingsViewModel: NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
            RefreshLanguagesOnAppearing();
        }

        public void RefreshLanguagesOnAppearing()
        {
            Settings = "";
            Language = "";
        }

        private string settings;
        public string Settings
        {
            get { return settings; }
            set
            {
                settings = FilterTranslationDatabase(StaticShareProperties.selectedLanguageIndex);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string language;
        public string Language
        {
            get { return language; }
            set
            {
                //alternative call for stackoverflow question
                language = WorkAroundForStackOverflow();

                //standard call
                language = FilterTranslationDatabase(StaticShareProperties.selectedLanguageIndex);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string WorkAroundForStackOverflow()
        {
            string dummy = null;
            if (selectedIndex == 0) dummy = "lingua";
            else if (selectedIndex == 1) dummy = "language";
            return dummy;
        }

        private int selectedIndex;
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                selectedIndex = value;
                StaticShareProperties.selectedLanguageIndex = selectedIndex + 3;
                //plus 3 beacuse tranlations start from third column of database
                RefreshLanguagesOnAppearing();
            }
        }

        //language list to be shown in picker menu
        public List<string> LanguageList
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<string> { "Italiano", "English" };
            }
        }

        private string FilterTranslationDatabase(int indexLanguage, [CallerMemberName] string callerMember = "")
        {
            DataView dataview = App.dtTranslations.DefaultView;
            dataview.RowFilter = App.dtTranslations.Columns[2].ToString() + "='" + callerMember.ToString() + "'";

            string translation = dataview.ToTable().Rows[0][indexLanguage].ToString();
            return translation;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have finally my property changed implemented as well

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace HeatLoadApp_MAUI.Utilities
{
    public class NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is `NotifyPropertyChanged` a typo?  It should be `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: What the f**k!!! I just forgot to to put                                                                     public class NotifyPropertyChanged:INotifyPropertyChanged when inherit from the Interface was missing!! you saved my life! Working perfectly right now! Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

FYI: As an alternative to writing your own `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementor, you can simply inherit from [Community Toolkits / MVVMToolkit / `ObservableObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject):

```cs
public class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject
...
```